# Is there a difference between [user] and [users]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging, tagging

The [user](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user) and [users](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/users) are seems to be the same thing. Even their tag info is kinda identical. Shouldn't they merged and one be a synonym for the other?

Comment: Agreed.  Can someone who has at least 5 reputation in the user tag [propose *users* as a synonym](http://ux.stackexchange.com/tags/user/synonyms)?

Comment: @3nafish If it would need only 5 reputation I would have done it, but it need 2500:D The total answer score have to be 5:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no reason to keep them separate. I went and made them synonyms with [users](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/users) as the master tag (noun tags are generally made plural).